# Grooovy weird error

Tags: grails, groovy

```
 class Area {

        String name
        String description

        static constraints = {
        }
```

_

```
 class SearchIndexing {

        String search
        Area area

        static constraints = {
        }
    }
```

_

```
 <%

            def area = cm.Area.get(1)

            def si = new cm.SearchIndexing()

            def concat   

            concat = area.name // i wanna join here more things with much bigger class

            si.search = concat
            si.area = area
            si.save()

            out << searchIndexing.list()

            %>
```

ERROR:

```
No signature of method: cm.SearchIndexing.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), isCase(java.lang.Object), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you don't have an initial + sign, ie:

```
def temp = + obj2.prop1 + " " + ...
```

Why not try a more groovy way like:

```
def temp = "$obj2.prop1 $obj2.prop2 ..."
```

Or:

```
def temp = [ obj2.prop1, obj2.prop2 ].join( ' ' )
```

Comment: i updated the example with the real problem. please take a look now. I'm trying this way because it didnt worked in the controller it gave me the same error so i decided to try in a smaller class in a groovy style inside a gsp page.

Comment: @Victor I'm not even sure you can do what you're attempting in a `gsp`, it should be in a controller.  Even if it is possible, mixing presentation and logic **always** turns out to be a really bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

From the way you're creating the instance of `SearchIndexing`

```
def si = new cm.SearchIndexing()
```

it looks like it's an inner class. I don't think a domain class can be an inner class, which would explain why it has no `save()` method.